# Table Pagination in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, frontend

I would include a table with a pagination in my html page, I'm newbie so I'm trying to use [breedjs](http://jjppof.github.io/breedjs), but its not working.

Here is my code:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link href="Content/Site.css?v=0.16" rel="stylesheet" />
    
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
        <script>
            var data = { people: [{ age: 21, name: "Wells Ferrell", gender: "male", email: "wellsferrell@limozen.com" }, { age: 22, name: "Burton Pena", gender: "male", email: "burtonpena@limozen.com" }, { age: 22, name: "Buchanan Nelson", gender: "male", email: "buchanannelson@limozen.com" }, { age: 27, name: "Marshall Armstrong", gender: "male", email: "marshallarmstrong@limozen.com" }, { age: 21, name: "Sofia Dixon", gender: "female", email: "sofiadixon@limozen.com" }, { age: 38, name: "Kent Mason", gender: "male", email: "kentmason@limozen.com" }, { age: 21, name: "Cummings Rodgers", gender: "male", email: "cummingsrodgers@limozen.com" }, { age: 27, name: "Lorrie Haynes", gender: "female", email: "lorriehaynes@limozen.com" }] };
    
            function () {
                breed.run({
                    scope: 'people',
                    input: data,
                    runEnd: function () {
                        for (i = 1; i <= breed.getPageCount('people'); i++) {
                            $('ul').append(
                                $('<li>', {
                                    html: i,
                                    onclick: "breed.paginate({scope: 'people', page: " + i + "});"
                                })
                            );
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    
        <title class="appName"></title>
    
    </head>
    <body id="page-top">
    
                <div style="background-color:white">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Gender</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr b-scope="people" b-loop="person in people" b-paginate="5">
                                <td>{{person.name}}</td>
                                <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
                                <td>{{person.age}}</td>
                                <td>{{person.email}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <ul></ul>
                </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Moreover, I included the file breedjs.min.js under my scripts folder, but I didn't get how would it works.

What I'm doing wrong?

Is there a easiest way to do it?

Comment: Did you check the console for any errors ?

Comment: I have this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name

Comment: Please update your question with this error.

Answer (score 1):

The console error is due to the fact that, the `breed.run` is inside a function statement without a name.

Eg:

```
function foo() { 
  console.log('hello');
}
```

and then call it `foo()`.

Comment: I made the adjustment but Its not working anyway, with no error in console.

Comment: Please update the question with your current code.